# Laravel api route not working, getting 404 error

Tags: laravel

I have a api route `Route::get('{user_id}', 'Api/ApiProfileController@getUserAndPosts');`

And method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

class ApiProfileController extends Controller {

public function getUserAndPosts($user_id) {
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    if($user) {
        $post = $user->profile()->get();
        return response()->json([$user, $post], 200);
    }
}

}
```

When I try to call a route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getUserAndPosts/2`, I get a 404 error

Comment: You controller located on `/Controllers/Api/ApiProfileController.php`?

Comment: yes, writes that the controller was not found

Comment: Make sure the path `/Controllers/Api/ApiProfileController.php` or `/Controllers/ApiProfileController.php` oe something

Answer (score 0):

The name of your class is `ApiProfileController` , you are calling it with `ProfileController`

Comment: I sealed myself here

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in your route...

```
Route::get('getUserAndPosts/{user_id}','Api/ApiProfileController@getUserAndPosts');
```

Comment: No, I have a different route

Comment: route define in api.php or web.php??

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to change to route name in api.php because the route you show in api.php doesn't match with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getUserAndPosts/2`

You will need to add getUserAndPosts to your api in api.php, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an api route, try to send the header with

```
Accept: "application/json"
```